# Intermittent error accessing Azure key vault - Keyset does not exists

Tags: c#, .net, azure, x509certificate, azure-keyvault

I am using Azure Key Vault in my MVC web application. I connect to the Key Vault using certificate. Below is my sample code

```
AssertionCert = GetCertificate(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[KeyVaultConstant.ApplicationID], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[KeyVaultConstant.CertificateThumbprint], false);    
var keyClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback((authority, resource, scope) => GetToken(authority, resource, scope, AssertionCert)));
var secrets = keyClient.GetSecretsAsync(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VaultUri"]).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

On some instances I get an error stating
**Cryptographic Exception: Keyset does not exists**

On research I found that I have to give IIS_IUser permission to the folder where primary key is stored. I did that, Yet once in a while I get this error. This does NOT happen everytime.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the permission issue . Here are the troubleshooting steps for the same:

**Troubleshooting Steps:**

- First check the service account which is running CRM App pool or ADFS App pool
- Now open certificate manager, in personal store, locate your certificate. Right click on the certificate and select "Managed Private Keys" option
- In the permission window, check if your app pool service account is given appropriate permission (Read permission should be fine, otherwise you can give Full control)
- In below screenshot I have given full permission on my wildcard certificate *.test.local to my App Pool account – "test\AppPoolSvc"

[image]

- Once the permission is given, perform an IISRESET and try accessing.

For further reference , please [check](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/resolve-cryptographic-exception-sharp39keyset-does-not-exist-or-access-is-denied-issuesharp39). Also please try to restart the machine to see if it works.